# How do I Share a Wired DSL Connection as a hotspot?

Tags: 12.04, hot-spot, dsl

I have a Wired DSL Connection in my laptop, and I want to share this creating a hotspot.

Ubuntu 12.04
Dell Inspiron 1545

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is referred to as "ad-hoc" networking. Simply clicking the networking icon in the panel, and then clicking again on `Create New Wireless Network` should lead you to a point where further guidance is no longer necessary.

Should you want more information, perhaps about editing or deleting such networks, you can find some of my writings on [How to Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-in-ubuntu#.UqH9ULVdVCE).